# uiscrollview won't scroll when dragging on ios-charts subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios-charts

I have a ios-chart as a subview that takes up half the screen. When I pan up on any other subview it scrolls. But not when I pan on the chart.
I tried setting:

```
[self.chart setDefaultTouchEventsEnabled:YES];
//and
[self.chart setScaleEnabled:NO];
```

It says in the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Charts/2.1.0/Classes/ChartViewBase.html#/s:vC6Charts13ChartViewBase25defaultTouchEventsEnabledSb)

> defaultTouchEventsEnabled
> enables/disables default touch events to be handled. When disable, touches are not passed to parent views so scrolling inside a UIScrollView won’t work.

**What can I do to enable scrolling when panning/dragging on the chart?**

Answer (score 9):

I was struggling with this as well. Since I needed the chart to be scrollable, @Entrabiter's solution didn't work for me. The only solution that worked for me, was assigning the delegate of the chart view's `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to my ViewController and implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

This solution is in Swift, but it should also work fine in Objective-C.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    // MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myChart: LineChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let gestureRecognizers = myChart.gestureRecognizers {
            for gestureRecongnizer in gestureRecognizers {
                if gestureRecongnizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer {
                    gestureRecongnizer.delegate = self
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The important part is to tell the gestureRecognizer to recognize both the scrollview's panGestureRecognizer as well as the chartview's panGestureRecognizer.

```
// MARK: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if otherGestureRecognizer == contentView.panGestureRecognizer {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `userInteractionEnabled` on the chart view to `NO`.

Comment: That worked. But now I'm unable to tap on my points.  Is there a way to have it both ways?

Comment: @Entrabiter what chart library are you using?

Comment: @Entrabiter The reason this is happening is that the chart library is eating up all the touches. You'll somehow have to figure out a way to delay touches that go into the chart view to let the scroll view intercept them if you're making a drag gesture.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out...
I removed all the UIPanGestureRecognizers from the ios-charts subview.
This allowed for the scrollview to handle all the pan events.

```
for(UIGestureRecognizer *rec in self.chart.gestureRecognizers){
    if([rec isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]){
        [self.chart removeGestureRecognizer:rec];
    }
}
```